# Pagination with neo4j (Graph DB)

Tags: pagination, neo4j, graph-databases

Currently am working in NEO4J and iam new in graph db. Now i need to paginate the records from graph db. And i created the following query

```
MATCH (n:Question)<-[r1:HAS_QUESTION]-(c:Chapter) 
MATCH (c)-[r2:HAS_CHILD]->(t:Topic)-[r3:HAS_QUESTION]->(qstn:Question) 
WHERE ID(c)=330 
WITH n,qstn WHERE NOT(n:Removed) AND NOT(qstn:Removed) 
WITH n,qstn 
RETURN n as Question,qstn
```

In this query i got 13 question nodes. But when i add skip and limit to that query , i got only 7 nodes instead of 10. The querys is

```
MATCH (n:Question)<-[r1:HAS_QUESTION]-(c:Chapter) 
MATCH (c)-[r2:HAS_CHILD]->(t:Topic)-[r3:HAS_QUESTION]->(qstn:Question)
WHERE id(c)=330 WITH n,qstn 
WHERE NOT(n:Removed) AND NOT(qstn:Removed) 
WITH n,qstn 
RETURN n as Question,qstn
SKIP 0 LIMIT 10;
```

Somebody please explain what is happening with this query. Is there any idea to get the 10 nodes.

The query for the sample graph is the following.

```
CREATE (c:Chapter {chapter_name:"Biodiversity and Conservation"})

CREATE (t:Topic {topic_name:"Biodiversity Conservation"})
CREATE (q:Question {content: "first question"})

CREATE (t1:Topic {topic_name:"Biodiversity"})
CREATE (q1:Question {content: "second question"})

CREATE (q0:Question {content: "third question"})
CREATE (q01:Question {content: "fourth question"})
CREATE (q2:Question {content: "fifth question"})
CREATE (q3:Question {content: "sixth question"})
CREATE (q4:Question {content: "seventh question"})
CREATE (q5:Question {content: "eighth question"})
CREATE (q6:Question {content: "nineth question"})
CREATE (q7:Question {content: "tenth question"})
CREATE (q8:Question {content: "eleventh question"})
CREATE (q9:Question {content: "twelfth question"})
CREATE (q10:Question {content: "thirteenth question"})
CREATE (q11:Question {content: "fourteenth question"})
CREATE (q12:Question {content: "fifteenth question"})
CREATE (q13:Question {content: "sixteenth question"})

CREATE (c)-[r:HAS_TOPIC]->(t)
CREATE (c)-[r1:HAS_TOPIC]->(t1)

CREATE (t)-[r2:HAS_QUESTION]->(q)
CREATE (t1)-[r3:HAS_QUESTION]->(q1)

CREATE (c)-[r4:HAS_QUESTION]->(q0)
CREATE (c)-[r5:HAS_QUESTION]->(q01)
CREATE (c)-[r6:HAS_QUESTION]->(q2)
CREATE (c)-[r7:HAS_QUESTION]->(q3)
CREATE (c)-[r8:HAS_QUESTION]->(q4)
CREATE (c)-[r9:HAS_QUESTION]->(q5)
CREATE (c)-[r0:HAS_QUESTION]->(q6)
CREATE (c)-[r11:HAS_QUESTION]->(q7)
CREATE (c)-[r12:HAS_QUESTION]->(q8)
CREATE (c)-[r13:HAS_QUESTION]->(q9)
CREATE (c)-[r14:HAS_QUESTION]->(q10)
CREATE (c)-[r15:HAS_QUESTION]->(q11)
CREATE (c)-[r16:HAS_QUESTION]->(q12)
CREATE (c)-[r17:HAS_QUESTION]->(q13)

return c,t,t1,q0,q01,q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10,q11,q12,q13,r,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r0,r11,
r12,r13,r14,r15,r16,r17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified my query in the following way.. Now it is working without any problem

```
START c = node({chapter_id}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH c-[r*..2]->(n:Question) 
WHERE NOT(n:Removed) 
RETURN DISTINCT n SKIP 0 LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

Which version do you use?

Can you share your graph so that we can reproduce the issue?

I simplified your query, could you try this one?

```
MATCH (n:Question)<-[:HAS_QUESTION]-(c:Chapter) 
WHERE id(c)=330 AND NOT(n:Removed)
MATCH (c)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(t:Topic)-[:HAS_QUESTION]->(qstn:Question)
WHERE NOT(qstn:Removed) 
RETURN n,qstn 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: My version is Neo4j 2.2.0

Comment: Graph structure is the following : Chapter-[:HAS_CHILD]->Topic .Question node is a child of both Chapter and Topic node. Then i need to get all the active question nodes under that chapter.

Comment: The above query returns the same answer.

Comment: Is pagination is possible with graph db? (Not for a single node. When there is multiple relations it is not working properly in my case.)

Comment: Sure, it is. It is a basic functionality, it rather seems you ran into a bug.

Comment: Could you try to prefix your query with "PLANNER RULE "

Comment: And your graph structure is not enough, please provide the full cypher statement to create your sample graph.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.The query for the sample graph is given with the question now.